# Why Solaris Message Queue Getting Full?

Tags: unix, process, solaris

I am using below Solaris operating system -

```
uname -a

SunOS dcapp 5.11 11.3 sun4v sparc sun4v.
```

I have created 3 message queues here.  Suppose message queue names are

1. AAA ( process a)
2. BBB ( process b)
3. CCC (process c)

AAA sends a message to BBB and BBB pass it to CCC

AAA --> BBB ---> CCC

Both process a and process b, are accessing database (in read and write mode)

But sometimes I am getting BBB message queue is full. So that AAA cannot pass the message to BBB.

I have deleted the BBB qid using command `ipcrm -q`, but in few minutes the BBB queue was full again.

Then I deleted the shared memory for BBB using command `ipcrm -m`, but soon after that also BBB queue was full

My questions are

1. What could be the reasons for creating BBB message queue full?
2. How can I see the pending messages inside  BBB which are to be routed
   to CCC?
3. Can I increase the BBB queue size? present size of the queue is 65036 bytes.  If increase is possible how to do it?

Comment: You haven't posted enough information for anyone to be able to help.  What application creates the queues?  Do you have access to the source code? Why do you think deleting an entire queue is going to fix the problem?

Comment: Hi @AndrewHenle,